# StringField in mongodb requirements

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, documents

I am wondering if I can add a requirment to the setup of my User document to check for a specific string. The idea is when a User Document is created with an email address, I want to make sure the email is from a college so it should end in ".edu"
example:
"john.doe@college.edu" is acceptable but "john.doe@gmail.com" is not

Here is my code:

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role), default=[])
```

Comment: StringField object does not have that attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an optional [`regex` argument](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.StringField) you can define:

```
email = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True, regex=r'.*?boston\.edu$')
```

And, also, why not use a specific `EmailField` in this case:

```
email = db.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, regex=r'.*?boston\.edu$')
```

Comment: i believe this makes it so the whole field must equal .edu however i just want to the field to contain .edu

Comment: sorry I am very unfarmiliar with regex but how could i alter the code to make it require "boston.edu"?

Comment: Thank you for everything but 1 more question:
what if I want only 2 colleges now so boston.edu and mass.edu?
is there a way to put an or statement?

Comment: @LouisB sure: `.*?(boston|mass)\.edu$`